# Can I have two MaterialApp widgets in an app in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two questions with and "if" regarding the first question. As the title says I know it's better to have one MaterialApp in an App in Flutter and making Scaffold widgets for screens. But in a situation like this [App](https://github.com/MarcusNg/flutter_facebook_responsive_ui/tree/master) which I followed for learning purposes and it's really written well and very clean. but it uses "[TabBarView](https://github.com/MarcusNg/flutter_facebook_responsive_ui/blob/master/lib/screens/nav_screen.dart)" as a [default home](https://github.com/MarcusNg/flutter_facebook_responsive_ui/blob/e318966039bdc2ba22890382aa3cf8619639d33d/lib/main.dart#L20) for the entire app. So if I want to add another screen like "LoginSreen" that's not part of the "TabBarView" it's not inheriting the "MaterialApp" widget features. So I have to add a "MaterialApp" widget independently for that screen.
So the question is, is it ok to have two "MaterialApp" widgets in a situation like this?
if yes does it affect any variables that's shared among the screens like "SharedPreference"? or what does it affect?
If it's a bad behavior to have two "MaterialApp" widgets to in an App, Then how can you get rid of the "[NavScreen(](https://github.com/MarcusNg/flutter_facebook_responsive_ui/blob/master/lib/screens/nav_screen.dart))" and implement the TabBarView in the screens, Because I have tried many ways and looked at many of open source projects like [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/tabbed-app-bar) they have "TabBarView" widget as the body and start of the project.

Answer (score -2):

yes you can definitely  have two mat apps. but its not recommended.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).